# How to block page unload event for an async json call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to block the unload event for a page until I get a response from the server for an async json call initiated by the client.

To make it clear, the scenario is the following: I need to save the user changes into a database when they close the browser. While doing so, I will show a small `div` and hide it when we're done (hiding it doesn’t matter, the page will already be gone!)

In code, this is pretty much what I am trying to do. 
PS: I don’t want to use `alert()`

```
  
  window.onbeforeunload = function () {

        var requestURL = "../foo/Save";
        $("#dvMsg").show();

        $.getJSON(
            requestURL,
            {
                changeId: 1,
                userId: 1
            },
                function (data) { 
                    // hide the dvMsg 
                    $("#dvMsg").show();
                    // page should be safe to unload
                });

        };
```

The problem is the nature of the async call i.e. it will not block and the page will be unloaded before we get the response.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done at all if the event is asynchronous.

Why not make it synchronous? That's probably your best chance to get it through.

Comment: a flag and a while loop would do it, but am not going the path! ;p. do I need to change anything in my MVC controllers if I want to make a synchronous call?

Comment: well, to be honest, I never knew that I could use $.ajax to make a fully synchronous call. Thanks for the hint!